# How to transform a mathematical statement to its logical notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

The following statement had been proven. What I need help with is transforming it into its equivalent logical notation. Please check if my use of predicates and existential quantifier is correct.

There are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$.

Below is my attempt in writing the above statement in its logical notation:
$$
\begin{align}
P(x) &: x \in \mathbb{Z}\\
Q(x) &: x \in \mathbb{Z}\\
S(x,y) &: \sqrt{x+y}=\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}
\end{align}$$

$\exists x \; \exists y \; (P(x) \wedge Q(y)) \wedge S(x,y)$

Is this correct?

Comment: The language of first-ordr logic has both function symbols (which you can use to denote the square function, e.g. $sqrt(x)$ could be used to denote $\sqrt(x)$) and it has the = special predicate symbol as well. So, I would break this down to that level. Also, even if you don't go down to that level, you definitely want to take out the $P(x)$ and -$Q(x)$ predicates out of your definition of the $S(x,y)$ predicate and simply use $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Bram28 So is my answer incorrect?

Comment: $$\exists a, b\in\mathbb Z:\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt a+\sqrt b.$$

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran If you move the parenthesis and do $\exists x \ \exists y (P(x) \land Q(x) \land S(x,y))$ it could work ... but it wouldn't be avery practical translation. I mean, I could also represent it by $P$ if I define $P$ to be "There are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt{a +b }= \sqrt{a} +\sqrt{b}$" ... but that would not be very practical either.

Answer (score 1):

My variant:
$$(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z})(\sqrt{x + y} = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})$$

Comment: Need to use $x$ for $a$ and $y$ for $b$

Comment: @Bram28. Of course you are right, corrected. Thanks.